# Application ignoring css

Tags: css

I am trying to create 2 buttons of the same width that will look as following:
White text in a blue square with black border and with margin of lets say 5px from each side:
[image]

this is my css code:

```
a.button
{
    background-color: Blue;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: Black;
    color: White;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    width:100px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

But what I am getting is:
[image]

I am using Google Chrome browser, and when I click on "inspect element" I can see all my css properties there, but my application is ignoring them.

Comment: We'll need to see the html, too...

Comment: And what does your question have to do with C#? Maybe you can explain a little better what you are actually doing?

Comment: C# has nothing to do with it...

Comment: This question makes me feel bad for c#. It was all like "why you blaming me? I was just sitting here?!"

Comment: @John Fisher - This is my html: string html = String.Format("<a href=\"www.something.com\" title=\"Link\" class=\"button\">", contentId);
            html += String.Format("Press here</>");
            html += "</a>";
            return html;

Comment: why is this post marked "visual-studio-2008" and "C#"?  Isn't this plain CSS code being rendered in a browser?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry guys.. I changed the title :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your element an `inline-block`:

```
a.button
{
    background-color: Blue;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: Black;
    color: White;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    width:100px;
    margin: 5px;

    display: inline-block;
}
```

Not sure if the capitalized color names are helping either.

Comment: The capitalized color names will be fine. Also an `inline-block` may be applicable here. But without more context hard to say.

Comment: This is my html:  String.Format("<a href=\"www.something.com\" title=\"Link\" class=\"button\">", contentId); 
html += String.Format("Press here</>"); 
html += "</a>"; 
return html;

Comment: `inline-block` will make them inline, which won't really put the constant-width to good use. I can't say much either, though.

Comment: @user990635, what is `Press here</>`? Shouldn't you get rid of that `</>` part? It will surely confuse the browser's HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the border style (solid in your case)

Try the following

```
a.button
{
    background-color: Blue;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: White;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

You will need to adjust the css, and add hover and active states.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3tKS7/